# if part not executed

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var t=true;
    var f=false;
    var cheap;
    $('.day1').on('change', function (e) {
        if($(this).val() == "Saturday"){
            cheap = true;
        }
        else{
            cheap=false;
        }
    });
    if(cheap==true){
        $('.pricing1').change(function () {
        var price = parseFloat($('.total').data('base-price')) || 0;
        $('.pricing1').each(function (i, el) {
            price += parseFloat($('option:selected', el).data('cheap'));
            $('.total').val('$' + price.toFixed(2));
        });
        //console.log('cheap',cheap)
        });
    }
    else{
        $('.pricing').change(function () {
        var price = parseFloat($('.total').data('base-price')) || 0;
        $('.pricing').each(function (i, el) {
            price += parseFloat($('option:selected', el).data('price'));
            $('.total').val('$' + price.toFixed(2));
        });
        console.log('cheap',cheap)
        });
    }

});
```

The console reading returns true for cheap when saturday is selected. but the if part is not executed. Every time only else part is executed. logically it should execute the if part if cheap is true. and the console displays the cheap value to true so the value of cheap is true. This is weird!

Comment: `if (cheap == true)` is redundant (and unpleasant to the eye); use `if (cheap)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are registering the event handlers at the dom ready, at that point of time `cheap` has the value `false` so the if condition will not get satisfied so only the change handler in the else part will get registered.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var t = true;
    var f = false;
    var cheap;
    $('.day1').on('change', function (e) {
        if ($(this).val() == "Saturday") {
            cheap = true;
        } else {
            cheap = false;
        }
    });
    $('.pricing1').change(function () {
        if (cheap == true) {
            var price = parseFloat($('.total').data('base-price')) || 0;
            $('.pricing1').each(function (i, el) {
                price += parseFloat($('option:selected', el).data('cheap'));
                $('.total').val('$' + price.toFixed(2));
            });
            //console.log('cheap',cheap)
        } else {
            var price = parseFloat($('.total').data('base-price')) || 0;
            $('.pricing').each(function (i, el) {
                price += parseFloat($('option:selected', el).data('price'));
                $('.total').val('$' + price.toFixed(2));
            });
            console.log('cheap', cheap)
        }
    });

});
```

---

You can simplify the code to something like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var t = true;
    var f = false;
    var cheap;
    $('.day1').on('change', function (e) {
        if ($(this).val() == "Saturday") {
            cheap = true;
        } else {
            cheap = false;
        }
    });
    $('.pricing1').change(function () {
        var data = cheap ? 'cheap' : 'price';
        var price = parseFloat($('.total').data('base-price')) || 0;
        $('.pricing1').each(function (i, el) {
            price += parseFloat($('option:selected', el).data(data)) || 0;
        });
        $('.total').val('$' + price.toFixed(2));
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing,

```
 if(cheap==true){
```

to

```
 if(cheap === true){
```

For explanation, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/4193263) answer:

> The `==` operator will compare for equality after doing any necessary type conversions. The `===` operator will not do the conversion, so if two values are not the same type `===` will simply return false. It's this case where `===` will be faster, and may return a different result than `==`. In all other cases performance will be the same.

Comment: Please explain what is the difference

Comment: It's same string same type comparison .i.e equal value and equal type comparison. Well that might not help in your case, but that's worth for a try.